# PHP Form sends email but without the entered text

Tags: php, html, css, email

I got a form and want the filled out form to be sent to my email address.
My code doesn't work properly (I don't have much experience with PHP).
So - I get an email but without the entered text of the form.
What's missing or wrong in my code?

```html
<!--Contact-->
<section id="contact" class="get-in-touch">
  <h1 class="title">Contact <span>us!</span></h1>
  <p class="contact-p text-center">Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <form class="contact-form row" method="GET" action="contact_me.php">
    <div class="form-field col x-50">
      <input id="name" class="input-text js-input" type="text" required>
      <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field col x-50">
      <input id="email" class="input-text js-input" type="email" required>
      <label class="label" for="email">E-Mail</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field col x-100">
      <input id="message" class="input-text js-input" type="text" required>
      <label class="label" for="message">Message</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field col x-100 align-center">
      <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

```
    <?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email_address = $GET['email'];
$message = $GET['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'user@gmail.com'; //This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);          
?>
```

---

So I expected to get the email with the typed in name, email and message but I got just the text of the $email_body without the entered text of the user. It's just blank.

**The output looks like that:** [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4OwM.png) 
*You have received a new message from your website contact form.*

Here are the details:

Name:

Email:

Message:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<input />` elements need the `name=""` attribute to become available in `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate question/answer

Answer (score -5):

u have to use the mailto function then set a localhost and set a variable to send email and the admin name u can watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No8gaqsFdMw

Comment: This is a link-only answer - if the link dies, the answer contains no useful information. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/284827) or [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284827) for more information. Please edit your answer to summarise the salient points from the link so that if the link dies, your answer is still relevant.